# C#: Why does one of these threading examples deadlock and the other doesn't?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The follow code will lock:

```
static void Main()
{
    object lockA = new object();
    object lockB = new object();
    var up = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (lockA)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (lockB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here1");
            }
        }
    });
    var down = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (lockB)
        {
            lock (lockA)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here2");
            }

        }
    });
    up.Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But this code, taken from the C# .NET 70-483 book doesn't lock in Visual Studio 2013 running under debug mode.

```
static void Main()
        {
            object lockA = new object();
            object lockB = new object();
            var up = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (lockA)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    lock (lockB)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Here1");
                    }
                }
            });
            lock (lockB)
            {
                lock (lockA)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here2");
                }

            }
            up.Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Is there something special about the thread that main is running in or is there some simple detail in the implementation that I can't see. It doesn't say anything here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx that would give me an indication as to why.

My only other idea would be that the thread in which "up" was spawned has some special ability to enter a lock? If this is the reason why would that be important to allow your code to do?

Comment: Second case may  also deadlock. It is just a timing issue.

Comment: When something does not deadlock when you run it does not prove that it does not deadlock at all. Threading issues are difficult to investigate exactly for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's just random timing; in the second example, both locks around the second printing are probably entered before the thread for the first task has the time to start up. Add `Thread.Sleep(500)` before the last `lock (lockB)`, and you'll probably see it lock up too.